# Single regex to remove empty lines and double spaces from multiline input

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to combine two regex functions to clean up some textarea input. I wonder if it is even possible, or if I should keep it two separate ones (which work fine but aren't looking as pretty or clean).

I have adjusted either so that they utilize global and multiline (`/gm`) and are replaced by nothing (`''`). I tried with brackets and vertical/or lines in any position, but it never ends up giving the expected result, so I can only assume there is a way that I have overlooked or that I should keep it as is.

Regex 1: `/^\s+[\r\n]/gm`

Regex 2: `/^\s+| +(?= )|\s+$/gm`

Currently in JavaScript: `string.replace(/^\s+[\r\n]/gm,'').replace(/^\s+| +(?= )|\s+$/gm,'')`

The goal is to remove:

- Empty spaces in the beginning and end of each line
- Empty lines (including any in the very beginning and end)
- Double spaces

Without it ending up on one and the same line. The single line breaks (`\r\n`) should still be there in the end.

Regex 1 is to remove any empty line (`^\s+[\r\n]`), Regex 2 does the trimming of whitespaces in the beginning (`^\s+`) and end (`\s+$`), and removes double (and triple, quadriple, etc) spaces in between (`+(?= )`).

Input:

```
   Let's  
make   this
 look

 a    little


    nicer   
  and 
more   

readible
```

Output:

```
Let's
make this
look
a little
nicer
and
more
readible
```

**Edit:** Many thanks to [Wiktor Stribiżew and his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59957000/single-regex-to-remove-empty-lines-and-double-spaces-from-multiline-input?noredirect=1#comment106033089_59957000) for this complete solution:

`/^\s*$[\r\n]*|^[^\S\r\n]+|[^\S\r\n]+$|([^\S\r\n]){2,}|\s+$(?![^])/gm`

Comment: Try `s.replace(/^\s*$[\r\n]*|^[^\S\r\n]+|[^\S\r\n]+$|([^\S\r\n]){2,}/gm, '$1')`. To also remove the trailing line breaks, add `|\s+$(?![^])` to the end of the pattern.

Comment: Start with `/^\s*\n|^\s+/gm` to remove empty lines and empty spaces in the beginning and end of lines. It doesn't cover the double spaces between words.

Comment: @BojanBedrač it definitely does most of it, especially when adding `+(?= )` for the double spaces and Wiktor's `|\s+$(?![^])` for the trailing line break. Unfortunately, spaces in the end of the lines are still there.

Comment: @BojanBedrač This hackery, however, would work: `/^\s*[\r\n]|^\s+| +(?= )| +$|\s+$(?![^])/gm`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest the following expression with a substitution template `"$1$2"` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/8qbExt/1/)):

`/^\s*|\s*$|\s*(\r?\n)\s*|(\s)\s+/g`

**Explanation:**

- `^\s*` - matches whitespace from the text beginning
- `\s*$` - matches whitespace from the text ending
- `\s*(\r?\n)\s*` - matches whitespace between two words located in different lines, captures one CRLF to group `$1`
- `(\s)\s+` - captures the first whitespace char in a sequence of 2+ whitespace chars to group `$2`

Comment: Whoa, that's clean! Thank you so much!