# Javascript Displaying Data From Local Storage Array Problem

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dom, local-storage

I'm creating a Simple CRUD Application with Javascript and I'm having a problem in Display Data Table from local Storage.

It's like making a TODO List but this is with a Table and enter the data in one row and in a column.

I don't know how to explain the problem clearly, the important thing is that I want the results from my input form and submit to local storage to be displayed correctly in the table.

This is The Code :

```js
const 
  myForm       = document.forms['my-form']  // form name pada tag html form
, table        = document.querySelector('#myTable tbody')
, dataArr       = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('dataArr') || '[]');

var selectedRow = null
var number = 0

// Tabel init
dataArr.forEach(row=>{
    let newRow = table.insertRow()

    newRow.insertCell().textContent = row.no = ++number
    newRow.insertCell().textContent = row.inputNL
    newRow.insertCell().textContent = row.inputJK
    newRow.insertCell().textContent = row.inputNH
    newRow.insertCell().textContent = row.inputA 
    newRow.insertCell().innerHTML = `<a onClick="onDelete(this)"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a>`
})

function onFormSubmit() {
    if (validate()) {
        if (selectedRow == null) {
            // Menambahkan entri ke LocalStorage :
            dataArr.push(Object.fromEntries(new FormData(myForm).entries()))
            localStorage.setItem('dataArr', JSON.stringify( dataArr ))
            
            // Memasukkan Data pada Baris Baru
            let newRow = table.insertRow()
            
            newRow.insertCell().textContent = myForm.no.value = ++number
            newRow.insertCell().textContent = myForm.inputNL.value
            newRow.insertCell().textContent = myForm.inputJK.value
            newRow.insertCell().textContent = myForm.inputNH.value
            newRow.insertCell().textContent = myForm.inputA.value
            newRow.insertCell().innerHTML = `<a onClick="onDelete(this)"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a>` 
        } 
        resetForm();
    }
}

// Function untuk Mereset Data yang sudah diSumbit di dalam Input
function resetForm() {
    document.getElementById("no").value = "";
    document.getElementById("inputNL").value = "";
    document.getElementById("inputJK").value = "Pria";
    document.getElementById("inputNH").value = "";
    document.getElementById("inputA").value = "";
    selectedRow = null;
}

// Function untuk Delete Data
function onDelete(td) {
    if (confirm('Apa kamu yakin ingin Menghapus Data ini?')) {
        row = td.parentElement.parentElement;
        document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(row.rowIndex);
        resetForm();
    }
    hapusDataLocal(td.parentElement.parentElement)
}

function hapusDataLocal(dataItem) {    
    dataArr.forEach(function(task, index) {
        if (dataItem.textContent === task ) {            
            dataArr.splice(index, 1);
        }
    });
    localStorage.setItem(dataArr, JSON.stringify(dataArr))
}

// Function untuk Memvalidasi Data
function validate() {
    isValid = true;
    if (document.getElementById("inputNL").value == "" || document.getElementById("inputJK").value == "" || document.getElementById("inputNH").value == "" || document.getElementById("inputA").value == "") {
        isValid = false;
        alert("Isi Semua Formnya dengan Benar!");
    } 
    return isValid;
}
```

```html
    <!-- Registration Form -->
    <div class="container w-50 mt-3 shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded">
      <div class="p-3">
          <h1 class="mb-4">Registration Form</h1>
            <form class="task-form" name="my-form" onsubmit="event.preventDefault();onFormSubmit();" autocomplete="off">
              <input type="hidden" name="no" id="no" value=""> 
              <label for="inputNL" class="form-label">Nama Lengkap</label>
              <input type="text" id="inputNL" name="inputNL" class="form-control mb-2" placeholder="Nama Lengkap">
              <label for="inputJK"class="form-label">Jenis Kelamin</label>
              <select class="form-select mb-2" id="inputJK" name="inputJK">
                <option value="Pria">Pria</option>
                <option value="Wanita">Wanita</option>
              </select>            
              <label for="inputNH" class="form-label">No HP</label>
              <input type="number" id="inputNH" name="inputNH" class="form-control mb-2" placeholder="No HP">
              <label for="inputA" class="form-label">Alamat</label>
              <textarea id="inputA" name="inputA" class="form-control mb-2" style="min-width: 100%" placeholder="Alamat"></textarea>
              <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md my-3">
            </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Table -->
    <div class="container mt-3 shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded">
      <div class="p-3">
        <table class="table" id="myTable">
          <thead>
              <th scope="col">#</th>
              <th scope="col">Nama Lengkap</th>
              <th scope="col">Jenis Kelamin</th>
              <th scope="col">No HP</th>
              <th scope="col">Alamat</th>
              <th scope="col">Aksi</th>
          </thead>
          <tbody>

          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>      
    </div>
```

Here is The Problem in The Table, The data does not match the column.

[image]

And the actual result I want is like this.

[image]

Comment: where is `onFormSubmit` ? Please provide a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as recommanded https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have edited the javascript code, please check again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all:

1. change

```html
 <form class="task-form" name="my-form" onsubmit="event.preventDefault();onFormSubmit();" autocomplete="off">
```

to

```html
 <form class="task-form" name="my-form" autocomplete="off">
```

Js code for that is :

```js
const 
  myForm = document.forms['my-form']  // form name pada tag html form

//.... 

myForm.onsubmit = e =>
  {
  e.preventDefault() 
  //...
```

2. add my CSS from snippet below (masked)

> How do you delete the local storage data?

There were some inconsistencies in the management of `no`.
I made a few other fixes.
Deleting a `<table><TR>` works...

And please don't use `getElementById` for form elements!
see how I coded your `validate()` function
see my previous posts on this point : [Jun 30 at 13:06](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68194437/how-to-show-css-animation-in-form-with-javascript-validation-only-when-input-is/68195398#68195398) and [Jun 14 '19 at 14:17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56599831/was-the-name-attribute-really-needed-in-html/56600018#56600018)

> I'm like all coders, once I get started on a project I can't just leave it halfway. I hope this will help you better finalize yours.

I got a bit of a headache on the display of the text address transposed in the table, with its overflow problems; hence the idea of the regex to at least remove unnecessary white lines ...
so, see also [Single regex to remove empty lines and double spaces from multiline input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59957000/single-regex-to-remove-empty-lines-and-double-spaces-from-multiline-input)

```js
const 
  myForm  = document.forms['my-form']  // form name pada tag html form
, myTable = document.querySelector('#myTable')
, myTbody = document.querySelector('#myTable tbody')
, dataArr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('dataArr') || '[]')
, rowsInfo =
    { last_no  : 0
    , noSelect : true
    , index    : 0
    , tRow     : null
    }
, addTableRow = row =>
    {
    rowsInfo.last_no = Math.max( rowsInfo.last_no, row.no )

    let newRow = myTbody.insertRow()
      newRow.insertCell().textContent = row.no 
      newRow.insertCell().textContent = row.inputNL
      newRow.insertCell().textContent = row.inputJK
      newRow.insertCell().textContent = row.inputNH
      newRow.insertCell().innerHTML = `<div>${row.inputA}</div>`
      newRow.insertCell().innerHTML = `<i class="fas fa-times"></i>`
    };
dataArr.forEach(addTableRow) // Tabel init
  ;
myForm.onsubmit = e =>
  {
  e.preventDefault() 
  if (validate())
    {
    if (rowsInfo.noSelect)
      {
      let newRow = Object.fromEntries(new FormData(myForm).entries())
      newRow.no  = ++rowsInfo.last_no

      dataArr.push(newRow)
      addTableRow (newRow) // Memasukkan Data pada Baris Baru
      } 
    else
      {
      let
        index = rowsInfo.index
      , eTR   = rowsInfo.tRow
        ;
      eTR.cells[1].textContent = dataArr[index].inputNL = myForm.inputNL.value 
      eTR.cells[2].textContent = dataArr[index].inputJK = myForm.inputJK.value 
      eTR.cells[3].textContent = dataArr[index].inputNH = myForm.inputNH.value 
      dataArr[index].inputA    = myForm.inputA.value 
      eTR.cells[4].innerHTML   = `<div>${myForm.inputA.value}</div>`

      eTR.classList.remove('selected')
      }
    localStorage.setItem('dataArr', JSON.stringify( dataArr )) // Menambahkan entri ke LocalStorage 
    resetForm()
    }
  }
function resetForm() // Function untuk Mereset Data yang sudah diSumbit di dalam Input
  {
  myForm.reset()
  rowsInfo.noSelect = true
  }
function validate()  // Function untuk Memvalidasi Data
  {
  myForm.inputNL.value = myForm.inputNL.value.trim()
  myForm.inputJK.value = myForm.inputJK.value.trim()
  myForm.inputNH.value = myForm.inputNH.value.trim()
  myForm.inputA.value  = myForm.inputA.value.replace(/^\s*$[\r\n]*|^[^\S\r\n]+|[^\S\r\n]+$|([^\S\r\n]){2,}/gm, '$1') 
  myForm.inputA.value  = myForm.inputA.value.replace(/\n*$/, '')  // remove final line break

  let isValid = 
    ( myForm.inputNL.value !== '' 
   && myForm.inputJK.value !== '' 
   && myForm.inputNH.value !== ''
   && myForm.inputA.value  !== '' 
    ) 
  if (!isValid) alert('Isi Semua Formnya dengan Benar!')
    ;
  return isValid
  }
myTbody.onclick = ({target}) =>
  {
  let
    eTR   = target.closest('tr')
  , rowNo = parseInt( eTR.cells[0].textContent )
  , index = dataArr.findIndex(x=>x.no===rowNo)
  , isDel = target.matches('i.fa-times, td:nth-of-type(6)')
    ;
  if (!eTR.classList.toggle('selected') && !isDel )
    {
    resetForm()
    }
  else 
    {
    myTbody.querySelectorAll('tr').forEach(tr=>tr.classList.toggle('selected', eTR===tr))
 
    rowsInfo.noSelect    = false
    rowsInfo.index       = index
    rowsInfo.tRow        = eTR
    myForm.no.value      = dataArr[index].no
    myForm.inputNL.value = dataArr[index].inputNL
    myForm.inputJK.value = dataArr[index].inputJK
    myForm.inputNH.value = dataArr[index].inputNH
    myForm.inputA.value  = dataArr[index].inputA
    
    if (isDel && confirm('Apa kamu yakin ingin Menghapus Data ini?'))
      {
      dataArr.splice(index, 1)
      myTable.deleteRow(eTR.rowIndex)
      localStorage.setItem('dataArr', JSON.stringify(dataArr))
      resetForm()
      rowsInfo.last_no = dataArr.reduce((mx,{no})=>Math.max(mx,no),0)
      } 
  } }
```

```css
#myTable {
  table-layout : fixed;  /* one of the Boostrap always missing... */
  }
#myTable tbody tr.selected {
  background-color : darkblue;
  color            : whitesmoke;
  }
#myTable tbody tr:hover {
  background-color : lightblue; 
  cursor           : pointer; 
  }
#myTable tbody tr.selected:hover {
  background-color : #1c1ce0; 
  }
#myTable tbody td:nth-of-type(5) div { 
  max-height    : 1.2em;  /* no multilines displaying */
  white-space   : pre;
  overflow      : hidden;
  } 
#myTable th:nth-of-type(1), 
#myTable td:nth-of-type(1),
#myTable th:nth-of-type(6), 
#myTable td:nth-of-type(6) { 
  width      : 4em;
  text-align : center;
  }
#myTable tbody td:nth-of-type(6):hover { 
  color : red;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" 
      crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/all.css" >

<!-- Registration Form -->
<div class="container w-50 mt-3 shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded">
  <div class="p-3">
      <h1 class="mb-4">Registration Form</h1>
        <form class="task-form" name="my-form" autocomplete="off">
          <input type="hidden" name="no" id="no" value=""> 
          <label for="inputNL" class="form-label">Nama Lengkap</label>
          <input type="text" id="inputNL" name="inputNL" class="form-control mb-2" placeholder="Nama Lengkap">
          <label for="inputJK"class="form-label">Jenis Kelamin</label>
          <select class="form-select mb-2" id="inputJK" name="inputJK">
            <option value="Pria">Pria</option>
            <option value="Wanita">Wanita</option>
          </select>            
          <label for="inputNH" class="form-label">No HP</label>
          <input type="rowsInfo.last_no" id="inputNH" name="inputNH" class="form-control mb-2" placeholder="No HP">
          <label for="inputA" class="form-label">Alamat</label>
          <textarea id="inputA" name="inputA" class="form-control mb-2" style="min-width: 100%" placeholder="Alamat"></textarea>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md my-3">
        </form>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Table -->
<div class="container mt-3 shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded">
  <div class="p-3">
    <table class="table" id="myTable">
      <thead>
          <th scope="col">#</th>
          <th scope="col">Nama Lengkap</th>
          <th scope="col">Jenis Kelamin</th>
          <th scope="col">No HP</th>
          <th scope="col">Alamat</th>
          <th scope="col">Aksi</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody> </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>      
</div>
```

*localStorage object is considered has insecure into SO snippet*

PS: I use exclusively  [Whitesmiths style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style#Whitesmiths_style)

Answer (score 4):

do something like that...

```js
const 
  myForm       = document.forms['my-form']  // unique reference for ALL form's elements
, myTableTBody = document.querySelector('#myTable tbody')
, dataNL       = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('dataNL') || '[]')
  ;

// init table
dataNL.forEach(row=>
  {
  let newRow = myTableTBody.insertRow()

  newRow.insertCell().textContent = row.no
  newRow.insertCell().textContent = row.inputNL
  newRow.insertCell().textContent = row.inputJK
  newRow.insertCell().textContent = row.inputNH
  newRow.insertCell().textContent = row.inputA
  newRow.insertCell().textContent = ''  
  })

myForm.onsubmit = e =>
  {
  e.preventDefault()  

// add entries into local storage :
  dataNL.push(Object.fromEntries(new FormData(myForm).entries()))
  localStorage.setItem('dataNL', JSON.stringify( dataNL ))

// insert new row 

  let newRow = myTableTBody.insertRow()

  newRow.insertCell().textContent = myForm.no.value
  newRow.insertCell().textContent = myForm.inputNL.value
  newRow.insertCell().textContent = myForm.inputJK.value
  newRow.insertCell().textContent = myForm.inputNH.value
  newRow.insertCell().textContent = myForm.inputA.value
  newRow.insertCell().textContent = ''                   // Action
  }
```

[-> some help <-](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65570759/how-can-i-get-all-the-data-from-a-summited-form-and-make-that-into-a-new-list/65570895#65570895)

Comment: Bro I want to ask one more thing, namely How do I delete data in LocalStorage

Comment: With those like your answer above, How do you delete the local storage data?

Comment: The problem is still the same, how to delete item row in column ? I have edited the code in the code snippet for my question, please check what is wrong @Mister Jojo

Comment: No i use Bootstrap 5.1.0